# Request redirection handler

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have win forms client application that should communicate with third party web services. Web services requires specific authentication and I should keep it secured from win forms client. To do it, i created HttpHandler (IHttpHandler), that adds authentication header.

Please find following workflow:

1. Win forms application prepare web request for third party service and send it to my HttpHandler.
2. HttpHandler add authentification header
3. HttpHandler forward request to third party web service.(?)
4. Response directly returned to win forms application (this necessary, because the third party service can provide very big responses and these data shouldn't transfered through my HttpHandler).

How I can forward request to third party web service?

RewritePath - works only in boundaries of one application and it can't forward request to another domain.

Response.Redirect is not solution, because it only notifies win forms application to send request to new location and doesn't keep authentication header.

Comment: Where are you going to run your HttpHandler? Why dont you just add the authentication headers in your HttpRequest. IHttpHandler was designed to run in a Web Server to handle calls from a client, NOT to help a client get to a Web Service.

Comment: Is this WinForms or WebForms?

Comment: Why do you need a httphandler here? The authentication header can well be added by teh winform app...

Comment: If I add authentication header in winforms application, anyone can hack my credentials for third party web services.

Answer (score 0):

Could you create your own `HTTPWebRequest` and call the 3rd party webservices direct, consume the result, adapt to suit your needs and return that to your winforms client?nd